# reading line by line in c++ with while loop inside another while loop

Tags: c++, database, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, iostream

I have a problem in the following code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    string store;
    ofstream ip, ipa;
    bool ai = true;
    string catch, container, contain;
    ifstream datbot("database.txt"), datbrot("datafloor.txt");
    string chats, train;
    int loop = 0, c = 0;
    cout << "->>hi! I AM ALPHA" << endl;
    while (datbot.good())  //first loop
    {
        while (ai)  //second loop
        {
            loop = 0;
            c++;
            cout << c << ">>";
            // USER INPUT
            getline(cin, chats);
            // DATABASE LOOP CONTROL            
            unsigned int count = 0;
            // DATAFLOOR LOOP CONTROL
            unsigned int number = 0;

            while (loop == 0)  // third loop
            {
                loop++;
                cout << 'i' << endl;

                while (getline(datbot, container))  // final loop
                {
                    // cout << "pr" << endl;
                    count++;
                    catch = container;
                    // JUDGMENT TIME
                    if (catch == chats)
                    {
                        //LOOP OF HELL
                        while (getline(datbrot, contain))
                        {
                            num++;
                            // JUDGMENT TIME
                            if (number == count)
                                cout << "->>" << contain << endl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see on my code, there are four main while loops; the final loop is the loop to collect one line at a time, and, at first, it works perfectly. However, it is true and accessible on only the first run. It then is skipped while both the program is still running and other loops continue looping.

So my question is "Is there a way to keep the loop accessible when it is reached by the third loop while the program is still running, or can I keep the loop false after it has returned true?"

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. I am personally having an issue following your code. Specifically, it would be very helpful to add more descriptive comments as well as changing your variable names to describe their purpose better.

Comment: @DrakeJohnson ok it's done

Comment: It doesn't seem you changed anything in the code. All the variable names are the same and the commenting is unchanged.

Comment: @DrakeJohnson  I think my variables are good or you can give me an idea  of how you want them to be